# Phone Emulator on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I tried to use VIsual Studioi Community to create an Windows Phone App. It does work with my real Phone, but I want to use the Phone Emulator for obvious reason. 
I'm aware, that I have to enable Hyper-V to start it. But the error message I get, looks  a little strange. When I start Emulator 8.1 WVGA (or any other) I get this (german) message:

[image]

It says, that my operation system is not Windows 8. Well, it is Windows 10 with 64bit. So is there another Emulator for Windows 10?

Comment: I think it means you don't have a professional version of your OS (In This case Win 10 Pro)

Comment: Does your PC's processor come with virtualization extensions, like VT-x? You need a pro version of your SO, that has Hyper-V, and a processor that runs Hyper-V... Having that, try reinstalling the WP Virtual machines...